# Vertical align doesn't work on floated elements

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Hello I'm trying to get 2 elements vertically aligned.

```
<div>
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>LIs...</ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I want the h1 to float left, and the nav floated right. But vertical align doesn't work on floated elements :( Is their a way around this?

**edit:
with the table cell solution, the h1 loses its inline tight size. Is there any way around that?**

I've tried width:auto.

Comment: Use `display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle`, instad of `float`. Amazingly, it works.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure how this question is a duplicate of the linked question. This question refers to vertically-aligning two elements with respect to each other, whereas the linked question is about vertically positioning an element on the page.

Comment: Thanks, that was my initial attempt however the 2 elements end up side by side instead of one on the left one on the right :|

Comment: Ah. Hmm... I can't think of anything other than `<table>` to solve that (I don't use `display:table-*` CSS due to bad compatibility)

Comment: Seemed to of fixed it. Given the H1 1% width, and floated the ul inside the nav right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <h1 class="cell">heading</h1>
  <nav class="cell">
    <ul>LIs...</ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row{display:table-row;}
.cell{display:table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
border: 1px solid #CCC;}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2FCe/)